# How to draw squares and circles in my decision tree?

Tags: tikz-pgf, overleaf, flow-charts

I'd like to create a decision tree like the one shown below.

[image: decision tree]

```
\tikzstyle{decision} = [rectangle, minimum height=18pt, minimum width=18pt, draw=blue, fill=none, ultra thick, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{chance} = [circle, minimum width=18pt, draw=blue, fill=none, ultra thick, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw=none]
```

Comment: Like the figure.

Answer (score 4):

You can choose the shape of each individual child.

There's much, much more you can do though, including not needing to hardcode. I don't know much about Ti*k*Z trees / mindmaps, but there's a [tutorial](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#page.80) in the Ti*k*Z documentation, [examples](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/) on TeXample, plenty of packages to draw trees (e.g. [`forest`](https://ctan.org/pkg/forest) or [`tikz-qtree`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-qtree), among others), and the [trees](/questions/tagged/trees) tag on this website.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
level 1/.style={sibling distance=5cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
every node/.style = {draw, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=.75cm, anchor=north},
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)}]
]
\node[shape=ellipse, minimum height=1.25cm, minimum width=2cm] {R}
child { node[shape=rectangle, rounded corners] {A}
    child { node[shape=rectangle] {A} 
        child { node[shape=ellipse] {B} }
        child { node[shape=ellipse] {B} }
    }
    child { node[shape=ellipse] {B} }
}
child { node[shape=rectangle, rounded corners] {A} 
    child { node[shape=ellipse] {B} }
    child { node[shape=ellipse] {B} }
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]

Using the `tikzstyle`s you defined:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\tikzstyle{decision} = [rectangle, minimum height=18pt, minimum width=18pt, draw=blue, fill=none, ultra thick, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{chance} = [circle, minimum width=18pt, draw=blue, fill=none, ultra thick, inner sep=0pt]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw=none]

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[%
level 1/.style={sibling distance=5cm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=3cm},
every node/.style = {draw},
edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode.south) -- (\tikzchildnode.north)}]
]
\node[chance] {R}
child { node[decision] {A}
    child { node[decision] {A} 
        child { node[chance] {B} }
        child { node[chance] {B} }
    }
    child { node[chance] {B} }
}
child[decision] { node {A} 
    child { node[chance] {B} }
    child { node[chance] {B} }
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot]